# Where is the oracle db stored in windows

Tags: database, windows, oracle, oracle10g

Where are all the tables stored in oracle in windows?

I mean in which folder in windows.

Comment: They aren't stored separately they're in tablespaces. **YOU DO NOT WANT TO TOUCH THESE THOUGH**. It is a sure fire way to have a lot of pain.

Comment: Yes, you really don't want to be doing this. A tablespace is the data-structure in which Oracle stores things on the database. This is broken down on disk into multiple data-files per tablespace (if it's big enough). I'd recommend Googling a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select * from dba_data_files; -- The database files (this is where the tables live)
select * from v$logfile; -- The online redo logs
select * from v$controlfiles; -- The controlfiles
```